# My lua code runner is having a script error that im not sure how to fix

Tags: lua

whenever i try to run this code it say in an aplication called "Creat Your Frisk" it says "error in script encounter" ecounter: (line 48, char 3) 'end' expected near '' can someone help me/explain how to fix the issue?

```
function HandleItem(ItemID)
if ItemID == "Cinnamon Bon" then 
    Player.Heal (10)
    BattleDialogu ({"you regain 10 HP!"})
end
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/APlSe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function and `if` statement blocks are both terminated by an `end` statement.

```
function HandleItem(ItemID)
    if ItemID == "Cinnamon Bon" then 
        Player.Heal (10)
        BattleDialogu ({"you regain 10 HP!"})
    end
end
```